# Trying to update mysql table row through php

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm trying to update mysql table row through php.
I'm using joomla 3 as a system base.
What I'm doing is:

PHP page that show me a list of specific group of users:

```
$groupId = 10;

$access = new JAccess();
$members = $access->getUsersByGroup($groupId);

$rows = '<table id="hreilist"><tr>
        <th class="tblth2">ID</th>
        <th class="tblth3">Name</th>
        <th class="tblth4">Username</th>
        <th class="tblth5">E-Mail</th>
        <th class="tblth6">Status</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>';
foreach ($members as $id){
    $user = JFactory::getUser($id);
    $rows .= '<tr>';
    $rows .= '<td class="tblusers">' . $user->id . '</td>';
    $rows .= '<td class="tblusers">' . $user->name . '</td>'; 
    $rows .= '<td class="tblusers">' . $user->username . '</td>'; 
    $rows .= '<td class="tblusers">' . $user->email . '</td>';
    $rows .= '<td class="tblusers tblactive">' . $user->block . '</td>';
    $rows .= '<td class="tblusers tbldelete"><a href="modifiche/disableUser.php?id=' . $user->id . '">Delete</a></td>';
    $rows .= '</tr>';
}
$rows .= '</table>';

echo $rows;
```

Another PHP (disableUser.php) that should update the "users" table row on "delete" click

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$object = new stdClass();
$object->id = $_GET["id"];
$result = JFactory::getDbo()->updateObject('#__users', $object, 'id');
```

Comment: What is wrong? What I'm missing?

Comment: Ok, so whats the question? Do you get errors? What happens? What does not happen?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do not get any error, if I make a mouse over on "delete" it shows me the correct path of the second php file like https://example.com/modifiche/disableUser.php?id=1234 but finally it redirects me to the homepage

Comment: Solved.. I simply missing what I want to update... in this case $object->block = 1;